# how i can view file from mysql database using java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have a question in java :
I uploaded a  file (PDF, image …etc) to the mysql database
How to retrieve this?
i.e
How I can view these files?
Example: assume that uploaded  pdf file to database
Then in myApplication there exist a button called “View “. When clicking on it, will open PDF file.
———————————————————------------------------------------------------
I think the first step must be to download it on my computer and then use this code to open the file
`Desktop.getDeskTop().open(“File Path ”);`
That is right or not?
Thank you

Comment: check if this helps in your use case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557202/how-to-insert-and-retrieve-pdf-from-blob-using-java

Comment: You need to use a PDF API after having executed `getBinaryStream` on the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a table in the mysql database, but before creating table, we need to create database first.

```
create database sonoo;  
use sonoo;  
create table emp(id int(10),name varchar(40),age int(3));
```

sonoo is the database name, root is the username and password both.

```
import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
//here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

The above example will fetch all the records of emp table.

To connect java application with the mysql database, mysqlconnector.jar file is required to be loaded.

**Two ways to load the jar file**

1.Paste the mysqlconnector.jar file in jre/lib/ext folder

2.Set classpath

**Paste the mysqlconnector.jar file in JRE/lib/ext folder:**

Download the mysqlconnector.jar file. Go to jre/lib/ext folder and paste the jar file here.

**Set classpath:**

There are two ways to set the classpath:

-temporary

-permanent

**temporary**
open command prompt and write:
`C:>set classpath=c:\folder\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;`

**Permanent**

Go to environment variable then click on new tab. In variable name write classpath and in variable value paste the path to the mysqlconnector.jar file by appending mysqlconnector.jar;.; as
`C:\folder\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;.;`